# Is it possible to build an Electron app on Chromium OS instead of Chromium?

Tags: javascript, node.js, operating-system, electron, chromium

Can Electron be compiled into OS, based on Chromium OS instead of Chromium browser? At least theoretically.

So I can install my software without any OS. It can save some resources on kiosk-like projects, where noting will be used on machine, beside my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, it is not possible at the moment. Electron takes chromium's specific (libchromiumcontent) and integrates it with node.js, which chromium os does not support to execute natively.

Comment: Is there any way. to integrate this functionality in future? Any stopper?

Comment: Everything is stopper basically. You may architect code to not to use nodejs anymore to run on chromium os but that's no longer can be called as electron.

Comment: But if not use nodejs (theoretically), can it be based on chromiumOS and run without OS?

Comment: All of your saying is based on assumption you can separate those integration and execute chromium based binary on chromium os. Neither are possible. I don't know what's your usecase, but you may need try to achieve in other way - I don't believe those kind can be available in viable timeframe and probably won't even happen.